# Elastic Search Aggregation with scripting giving exception

Tags: elasticsearch

**Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException[-1]];**

I am using the following aggs query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "hscodes_eval": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fscode"
        },
        "aggs": {
                "top_6_fscodes": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "fscode",
                     "script": "doc[\"fscode\"].value[0..6]"
                  }
                }
              }
      }
  }
}
```

I want to get the count of documents matching the first 6 characters of field fscode. 
But I am getting above exception.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "hscodes_eval": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fscode"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_6_fscodes": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "fieldValue=doc['fscode'].value;if(fieldValue.length()>=7) fieldValue[0..6] else ''"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I wouldn't do it like this, meaning using a `script`. Scripts are usually slow and if you have many documents, it can add up pretty quickly.

Haven't thought much about this, but my gut feeling says I would try, **at indexing time**, to put in a [sub-field of `fscode`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/most-fields.html#_multifield_mapping) the first 6 characters of the initial `fscode`, maybe using a [truncate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-truncate-tokenfilter.html). Then, at search time, I would use a `terms` aggregation not on `fscode`, but on the subfield already defined.